TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeChild') in Next js 14
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeChild') , I get this error when I click the button to change the language when there is a page where I wrote the code, I researched and made updates, but I couldn't fix it. The project is built with Next js 14 and Typescript
"use client";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import LightGallery from "lightgallery/react";
import lgThumbnail from "lightgallery/plugins/thumbnail";
import lgZoom from "lightgallery/plugins/zoom";
import "lightgallery/css/lg-thumbnail.css";
import "lightgallery/css/lightgallery.css";
import "lightgallery/css/lg-zoom.css";

import PaginationCustom from "@/src/components/common/Pagination";
import { Container, Spinner } from "@/src/components/common";
import useClientData from "@/src/shared/hooks/useClientData";
import { formatDate } from "@/src/shared/custom/formatDate";
import { IGallery } from "@/containers/mediaGalery/models";
import { EndpointUrls } from "@/src/shared/constants/url";
import Error from "@/src/components/common/Error";
import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import { IMAGE_URL } from "@/api/routing";
import Image from "next/image";

interface IProps {
  langCode: number;
}

const Gallery: React.FC<IProps> = ({ langCode }) => {
  const [skip, setSkip] = useState(0);
  const [take, setTake] = useState(20);
  const [page, setPage] = useState<number>(0);
  const rowsPerPage = take;

  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const pageParams = searchParams.get("page");
  const numPage = Number(pageParams);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (numPage > 0) {
      setPage(numPage - 1);
      setSkip((numPage - 1) * rowsPerPage);
    }
  }, [numPage, rowsPerPage]);

  const { data, isLoading, isError } = useClientData<IGallery>( "MediaGallery", EndpointUrls.MEDIA_GALLERY(skip, take));

  if (isLoading) return <Spinner />;
  if (isError) return <Error />;

  return (
    <Container className="pt-12 pb-20">
      <div className="pb-8">
        {data?.datas ? (
          <LightGallery speed={500} plugins={[lgThumbnail, lgZoom]}>
            {data.datas.map((image, index) => (
              <a key={index} href={`${IMAGE_URL}${image?.imagePath}`}>
                <div className="relative overflow-hidden group w-full h-[218px]">
                  <Image
                    src={`${IMAGE_URL}${image?.imagePath}`}
                    alt="Large Image"
                    width={608}
                    height={377}
                    className="w-full h-full object-cover transition-all duration-1000"
                  />
                  <p className="absolute left-[10px] bottom-[10px] font-medium text-sm text-white z-10">
                    {image?.createdDate &&
                      formatDate(image.createdDate, langCode)}
                  </p>
                  <div className="absolute inset-0 bg-none group-hover:bg-custom-gradient transition-all duration-1000"></div>
                </div>
              </a>
            ))}
          </LightGallery>
        ) : (
          <p>No images available</p>
        )}
      </div>
      <PaginationCustom
        setPage={setPage}
        page={page}
        total={data?.totalCount || 0}
        rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
      />
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Gallery;

I downloaded the latest version of the library, I thought I got the error because the response was delayed, and I delayed the library, I searched on the Internet, but the information I found about it was not enough

Which button is being clicked? I do not see a button in the code you posted nor what data is changing.

where is the button?

The code is indeed incomplete. I'm facing the same issue. I can't share code in a comment, but I'll try and describe the problem. I'm using next-intl for my multilingual site and the error is thrown when there is a LightGallery on a page and a navigation to another locale occurs. The problem is that LightGallery is trying to do a cleanup (it's calling destroyGallery), but this only happens when the navigation is already done. So it's trying to remove DOM nodes that don't exist anymore. I'm not sure how NextJS Link behaves behind the scenes, but I guess both libraries are just incompatible.
